# Adding a new TextBox in a window after checking CheckBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm programming a simple app which is to take some input from a user and then proceed it.

I have two textBoxes which ask for user's name and surname. Then there are two textBoxes - one for Case1 and the second from Case2. I would like to get some additional information from the user. Those would be different after selecting Case1 or Case2.

After pressing Case1 or Case2 I would like to display (in the same window) new textBox widget (QLineEdit). Something like  `self.textbox_name = QLineEdit(self)` in my code below.

Here comes my problem. Is it possible to display different, new textBoxes after checking those checkBoxes and close them after clicking add?

There's my code here

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * #Imported one more module
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class AddRecord(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title='Add a record'
        self.left=10
        self.top=10
        self.width=640
        self.height=480
        self.initUI()
        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left,self.top,self.width,self.height)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('In progress')

        etykieta1 = QLabel("Name: ", self)
        etykieta1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(etykieta1.x(), etykieta1.y(), etykieta1.width()+50, etykieta1.height()))
        etykieta1.move(5, 5)       

        self.textbox_name = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox_name.move(150, 5)
        self.textbox_name.resize(280,25)   

        etykieta2 = QLabel("Surname: ", self)
        etykieta2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(etykieta1.x(), etykieta1.y(), etykieta1.width()+50, etykieta1.height()))
        etykieta2.move(5, 35)       

        self.textbox_surname = QLineEdit(self)
        self.textbox_surname.move(150, 40)
        self.textbox_surname.resize(280,25) 

        button_back = QPushButton('Add a record',self)
        button_back.clicked.connect(self.on_click)
        button_back.resize(200,32)
        button_back.move(0,425)    

        self.checkbox_case1 = QCheckBox("Case1",self)
        self.checkbox_case1.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.checkbox_case1.move(20,100)
        self.checkbox_case1.resize(320,40)

        self.checkbox_case2 = QCheckBox("Case2",self)
        self.checkbox_case2.stateChanged.connect(self.clickBox)
        self.checkbox_case2.move(130,100)
        self.checkbox_case2.resize(320,40)


        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):

        textboxValue_name = self.textbox_name.text()
        textboxValue_surname = self.textbox_surname.text()

        QMessageBox.question(self, 'Warning', 'NewRecordAdded.', QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.Ok)

        self.textbox_name.setText("")
        self.textbox_surname.setText("")

        print("Works well", textboxValue_name, textboxValue_surname)

        self.checkbox_case1.setChecked(False)
        self.checkbox_case2.setChecked(False)

    def clickBox(self, state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            print('Checked')  
        else:
            print('Unchecked')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AddRecord()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain what type of widgets do you want to show when you press Case1 or Case2?

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes. I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following observations about your logic:

- Use layouts to set the positions of the widgets.
- If you are going to handle many buttons like the QCheckBox it is advisable to use a QButtonGroup.

Going to the problem, you have to show or hide the widgets using the show(), hide() or setVisible() method as the case may be.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Add a record")

        self.statusBar().showMessage("In progress")

        self.name_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.surname_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        self.case1_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Case1")
        self.case2_checkbox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Case2")

        self.m_group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup(
            self, exclusive=False, buttonClicked=self.onButtonClicked
        )
        self.m_group.addButton(self.case1_checkbox)
        self.m_group.addButton(self.case2_checkbox)

        # hide textbox
        self.textbox_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.textbox_name.hide()

        self.add_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(
            "Add a record", clicked=self.on_click
        )
        self.add_button.setFixedSize(200, 32)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        flay.addRow("Name", self.name_edit)
        flay.addRow("Surname", self.surname_edit)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(self.case1_checkbox)
        hlay.addWidget(self.case2_checkbox)
        hlay.addStretch()

        vlay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        vlay.addLayout(flay)
        vlay.addLayout(hlay)
        vlay.addWidget(self.textbox_name)
        vlay.addStretch()
        vlay.addWidget(self.add_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def onButtonClicked(self):
        self.textbox_name.setVisible(self.m_group.checkedId() != -1)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_click(self):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(
            self,
            "Warning",
            "NewRecordAdded.",
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok,
            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Ok,
        )
        # restore
        self.name_edit.clear()
        self.surname_edit.clear()
        self.textbox_name.clear()
        self.textbox_name.hide()
        for button in self.m_group.buttons():
            button.setChecked(False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you check the code, no button has been added, only the visibility of the widget was used.

Comment: Thanks! Your code is brilliant. How can I add names to the textboxes in the easiest way?